# PG::UndefinedTable: ERROR: relation does not exist

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

Just playing around with building a rails app and I am pretty sure I did something dumb.  I ran a scaffold and misspelled the model Ave vs Afe.  I am sure I went through and changed everything in the migration files and view files etc. and even ran a search for 'ave' to see if I missed anything.  Anyway ran the migrations and now I get this:

```
PG::UndefinedTable: ERROR: relation "aves" does not exist LINE 5: WHERE a.attrelid = '"aves"'::regclass ^ : SELECT a.attname, format_type(a.atttypid, a.atttypmod), pg_get_expr(d.adbin, d.adrelid), a.attnotnull, a.atttypid, a.atttypmod FROM pg_attribute a LEFT JOIN pg_attrdef d ON a.attrelid = d.adrelid AND a.attnum = d.adnum WHERE a.attrelid = '"aves"'::regclass AND a.attnum > 0 AND NOT a.attisdropped ORDER BY a.attnum

Extracted source (around line #17):

15  # GET /afes/new
16  def new
17    @afe = Afe.new
18  end
19
20  # GET /afes/1/edit
```

I checked my postgsql indexes, schema and have even wiped my migrations and run rake:db:reset.  My schema, models and controllers are clean.  That old 'ave/aves' reference is no where to be found.  It looks like something hung up in active record but not sure where to start.

It's a dummy play app but I really don't want to start over.  Can I force the migrations to run again (if I un-delete them)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This has to do with pluralization rules, the rules used to make a plural form of a model name.

```
 ActiveSupport::Inflector.pluralize "afe"
   => "aves"
```

So Rails thinks the plural of `afe` is  `aves`.

You can fix your problem by renaming the table back to `aves` in your migration, or by adding this to `config/initializers/inflections.rb`:

```
ActiveSupport::Inflector.inflections do |inflect|
  inflect.irregular 'afe', 'afes'
end
```

Comment: Thanks! Never would have figured that out.  Was blinded by the coincidence that I misspelled the model with the same default plural form.